# The best way to fetch text from a UITextField and then put it in an external class?

Tags: c, ios, xcode

I have a password field on my app.
And I have the login code in a seperate class to keep things more clean in my ProjectsViewController.h .
But I have the declarations of the login text feilds in the ProjectsViewController.h.
How would I fetch the data from the login fields in login code class?
I have tried importing the main ProjectsViewController.h and then doing this:

```
NSLog(@"This is just an example kind of a thing:%@", TextFieldURL.text);
```

I have even tried getting the data from the login fields in the ProjectsViewController and then turning it into an NSString and then trying it but had no luck.

How would I go about doing this?
I have done this before, but cant remember for the life of me how I did it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking, but I will take a stab at it.

If you just want an object to be able to get the text, implement the following code into the class that has the `UITextField`:

.h file

```
- (NSString*) text; // can be something else, of course
```

.m file

```
- (NSString*) text; {
    return textFieldURL.text; // simple sends the text to another object when asked.
}
```

For the object that needs to get the text, assuming the class used above is called `SomeObject`:

```
SomeObject *object = // do something here, if necessary
NSString *textFieldText = [object text];
```

It should be that simple, if you only want to get the text from the other object. If this does not address the correct problem, please say so. By the way, you should rename `TextFieldURL` to `textFieldURL`, like I did, because variables are not supposed to start with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Sorry I didn't reply sooner! But, Im getting an issue with this:
011-11-24 11:30:19.925 MyTestProject[947:9203] (null) when it returns the text. Why is this?

Comment: Is everything allocated and initialized?

Comment: By the way, it would be much easier to help you if we had the code that deals with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want your login class to access the text fields directly to retrieve the text.

You could do this by passing your UITextField pointers to the login class so that it can request the text any time it wants.

Have you thought about switching it around and making the login class provide a login service that you pass the login credentials (text) to and it returns whether or not the user is authenticated?